# How to make my method read user input from another method?

Tags: java

I'm still trying to make the text editor to run with cmd but I'm stuck.

```
import java.util.Scanner;       

public class TextEd {

  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Editor editor = new Editor();
    editor.copiedText();
  }
}

class Editor {

 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

 public void copiedText() { 
    System.out.println("Paste your text here");
    String text = scan.nextLine();
    menu();
 }

 public void menu() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the text editor.\n"
    + "What do you want to do?\n"
    + "1. count characters"?;
    int choice = scan.nextInt();
    
    if (choice == 1) {
        counting();
    }
  }
    
  public void counting() {
    System.out.println(text.length());
  }
}
```

The problem is: everytime i try to execute i get an error "cannot find symbol 'text". I know I need to call it frim the other method, but hod do i do that?

Comment: declare a returntype and return the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yoy need to make it a class field:

```
class Editor {

 private Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 private String text = "";
 
 public void copiedText() { 
    System.out.println("Paste your text here");
    text = scan.nextLine();
    menu();
 }

 public void menu() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the text editor.\n"
    + "What do you want to do?\n"
    + "1. count characters"?;
    int choice = scan.nextInt();
    
    if (choice == 1) {
        counting();
    }
  }
    
  public void counting() {
    System.out.println(text.length());
  }
}
```

Also field `scan` in class `TextEd` seems to have no purpose and should therefore be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `text` as a local variable in `copiedText()`. Local variables cannot be seen in other methods. Try setting a field variable (a `private` variable in the `Editor` class) that can be seen by all methods

Answer (score 0):

your code has compile error because the parentheses in `System.out.println()` in `menu` are not closed properly.

you want to call a method of a `text` String in another method, so you can pass `text` to that method or just define it as a field in your class so that other methods can reach that variable.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TextEd {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Editor editor = new Editor();
        editor.copiedText();
    }
}

class Editor {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String text;

    public void copiedText() {

        System.out.println("Paste your text here");
        text = scan.nextLine();
        menu();
    }

    public void menu() {

        System.out.println("Welcome to the text editor.\n" 
        + "What do you want to do?\n"
        + "1. count characters?");
        int choice = scan.nextInt();

        if (choice == 1) {
            counting();
        }

    }

    public void counting() {

        System.out.println(text.length());
    }
}
```

be aware of blocks, every variable that is defined in other blocks or methods, is not reachable in other blocks or methods.